# Is there any alternative to search element in knockout js array instead of ko.utils.arrayFirst

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have one array which contains two things. First is Id and second is Value. I have all Id different but for some Id Values are common. The problem is when I am using ko.utils.arrayFirst it is giving me that Id which is available before than selected one, if the values are same. What I should do to display selected Id and Value.

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't included enough into in your question to give you a solid answer, but it sounds like what you want to do is make a `computedArray`

However, something like this would be along the lines of what you want:

```
vm.arrayOfWantedThings = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(vm.arrayOfEverything(), function(item) {
        return item.id() !== vm.wantedId()
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried computed array but it's giving only Values. It is not giving Id according to value.

Comment: I repeat: **You really haven't included enough into in your question to give you a solid answer**

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Underscore.js Arrays](http://underscorejs.org/#arrays) or some of [jQuery utilites](https://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) to perform common actions on arrays.